# Have an issue with mysqli prepared statement when trying to select info from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I am fairly new to MySQLi and prepared statements. Been following lots of tutorials recently to get to know how they work but still cant get this thing figured out. When new user tries to register I want to check if the username and email already exists in the db. The following code works when I do the check on 1 table but does not when I try to check multiple tables for existing entries. Ive tried join and cross join clauses as well as union and union all. The Dreamweaver shows no syntax errors but there have to be code issues somewhere. I was wondering if I have to set relation between tables in phpmyadmin before I can join the tables but I do not think this causes problem.

```
// check if the email is taken
    $check = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM parents JOIN leaders WHERE parents.email = ? OR leaders.email = ?"); 
    $check->bind_param("s", $input['email']);
    $check->execute();
    $check->store_result();
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `parents` and `leaders`? Do the `email` columns relate, or do you have 2 unrelated tables?

Comment: Also, you have 2 `?` placeholders, but only one bound param. `$check->bind_param("ss", $input['email'], $input['email'])` (provided the query is correct)

Comment: If you run this request in the mysql console with supposedly working values what do you get?

Comment: I am new to all that stuff. Both tables have the same structure and userid is set to primary key in both tables but I did not set a relationship between tables in phpmyadmin. I have 3 tables called guides, parents and leaders holding info about registered members of the site and I want to check all of them for existing entries. I have also tried bind_param 'ss' and that did not work either :(

Comment: I want to avoid having duplicate entries in all three tables when it comes to username and email. I would like to avoid adding radio buttons to select correct table when the users try to change their password. The code works correctly when only one table is selected and users can update their passwords flawlessly. I do not want leader to change password for the user existing in other table just because they share the same username and email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, given that you have 3 tables with the same structure, you want to `UNION` the tables together in one query, with one condition in the `WHERE` clause.

```
// UNION query to combine all three tables.
// The union is wrapped in a subquery to apply the single WHERE clause
// to the whole thing...
$sql = "
  SELECT email FROM (
    SELECT email FROM parents
    UNION SELECT email FROM leaders
    UNION SELECT email FROM guides
  ) combined
  WHERE email = ?";

if ($check = mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
  // Bind one input param
  $check->bind_param("s", $input['email']);
  $check->execute();
  $check->store_result();
  // Then fetch your row however you had planned to do so...
}
```

#### Note about the table structure:

Generally it is not recommended to have multiple tables with the same structure. Instead of 3 different tables here, you should have one table which combines all of them and has a column that identifies the type as `leader,guide,parent`.

Comment: I will try that. Hope it will work. Thanks for fast response :) I hope to become a good programmer in the future and this site seems to be a perfect place for newcomers into programming world.

Comment: This worked :) I knew I have missed something when tried to use UNION clause. Thank you very much.

Comment: Im glad Ive joined this forum. Guess I should have done it ages ago.

Comment: Will this work the same with UPDATE statement ? Or do I have to make some changes to the syntax ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Illumiele No I don't believe there's any support for `UPDATE` unions, or certainly nothing I've ever encountered. You can `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` and if you have some `user` table which holds the authoritative user_id for each of these, that might work, but if at all possible the best solution is to combine them all into one table.

Comment: would using join look like this; param->("SELECT password FROM parents JOIN leaders ON leaders.userid = parents.userid JOIN guides ON guides.userid = parents.userid WHERE userid = ?")

Comment: If I use 1 table instead of 3 tables will I be able to restrict leaders from accessing the same info as parents for example ?

Comment: @Illumiele The join would work that way only if all users existed in one of the tables. You would probably still need a union subquery to join against which builds a list of all possible users - it is complicated.  If you use _one_ table, then your application code just needs to query it correctly to only show the data to those privileged to view it. Your application does that already anyway by choosing which table to query. instead, you would modify the `WHERE` clause:  `...WHERE usertype = 'parent'`

Comment: Ive restructured my db and only using 1 table now as it will be a lot easier and I dont really need 3 tables in this case and I can create second table called permissions to restrict different users from accessing the same information :) Thanks for your help any way.

Comment: Would you be able to test my login and registration system when I am done with it ?? I would like to get some feedback on my system form experienced developers :) It is college work and I am not fussy about content. I'm only concerned about login system to make use of it for my graded unit. Thanks